# How to display a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn without a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This might by a silly question, but I was wondering if there was a way to have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in my DGV, but instead of showing the ugly combobox, it is just a white cell - when the cell is clicked, the dropdown shows up.

My problem is basically that this is really ugly: [image: this]

How do you get around this? I am used to working in WPF, not Winforms. Is it possible to just hide the combobox, but have the cell function the exact same way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBoxes have three different appearances you can choose from. In this case you're looking for `flat appearance`. But if you want a beautiful datagridview you might want to check out [PF Grid Toolkit](http://www.pfgrid.com/). It goes for quite an affordable price.

NB: [This page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18172/Appearance-Customizable-ComboBox) could also prove useful.

Comment: worked like a charm. Set cmbCol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you would want to handle the cell formatting event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx